# Покрывающий индекс на две таблицы

Tags: sql-server, настройка

Обычно в mssql можно создать кластеризированый индекс в пределах одной таблицы. Можно ли создать [покрывающий](http://habr.com/post/247373/) индекс состоящий из `id` и `value` соседней `table2`.

Например, есть `table1 (id, id_user)` (полей куча) и `table2(id,value)` (полей куча). Можно ли заиндексировать для `table1` по полю `id_user` значения `id_user=id,value` таблицы `table2` создав кластеризированый, некластеризированый или какой либо другой индекс?

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Comment: Вьюху кластерную попробуйте создать